# Xamarin ControlTemplate set BindingContext

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a contentcontrol to reuse some layout code.
Now I want to display the contentcontrol twice on one page, but with different content. How can I set the Binding Context of the ContentControl, so that it displays firstItem.Title in the first ContentView, and secondItem.Title in the second ContentView?

Shortened Code, just to view what i mean:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="ContainerControl">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Display the first item -->
    <ContentView Item="{Binding firstItem}" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ContainerControl" />

    <!-- Display the second item -->
    <ContentView Item="{Binding secondItem}" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ContainerControl" />
```

Item Class / ViewModel Properties:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public Item firstItem
{
    get;
    set;
}

public Item secondItem
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should use a ListView.

Comment: I can't use that, as both contentviews are in the same spot, and are dynamically set to visible / invisible